# shear formula confusion

Tags: structural-engineering

In the notes, the author stated that the shear stress is constant over the bottom face of the segment ... why in figure 7-4 , we can see that the shear stress varies ?

[image: shear formula 1]
Which is correct ? The red circled part or the figure ?

[image: shear formula 2]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the 3D view of Figure 7.4c, it explains this quite clearly. The shear stress varies along the beam's **height**. Along its **width** (such as along the bottom face), the stress is indeed constant.

Comment: ok , can you explain why the shear stress is varied linearly over the part ? if the stress varies linearly over a section , then it's normal stress, right ? from my book , shear stress only varies parabolically over a section , where the shear stress is max at the neutral axis , 0 at the top and the bottom part

Comment: In Eq. (7-2), $A'$ is not a constant - it depends on the value of $\bar y'$. You are almost correct - the shear varies parabolically *for a section with constant width*. For an arbitrary shaped section (e.g. a circular rod, or an I-beam) the variation is not parabolic, but it does satisfy Eq. (7-2).